# What is the proper testable way to include lodash in an Angular 2 / 4 App?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, automated-tests, lodash

I have an angular 4 app that uses lodash. In reading about angular 4, most everything get's included via dependency injection to make testing easier.

Do I need to worry about using DI for lodash and if so, how do I go about setting that up for my project?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should use DI to make your code loosely coupled.

In this case you should creating an underscore injectable dependency. For creating the same [`OpaqueToken`](https://angular.io/api/core/OpaqueToken) would be useful.

**common/underscore.service.ts**

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core'
declare let _: any ; //just typescript to consider _ API is available

export let UNDERSCORE = new OpaqueToken('UNDERSCORE');
export const loadDashProvider = [
   { provide: UNDERSCORE, useClass: _}
];
```

**AppModule**

```
//imports here

declare let _: any ; //just typescript to consider _ API is available

@NgModule({
   declarations: [...],
   imports: [...],
   providers: [
      //... other dependecies ... ,
      loadDashProvider
   ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Whenever you want to access `_` js API you could use `UNDERSCORE` token inside your class constructor which will eventually brings `_` API in it.